# Group Capturing

Tags: regex, kotlin

Hello everyone I am trying to figure out how to use the results of group capturing from regex in kotlin and for the life of me cannot find anything online. I basically just want to strip the "k" in short

```
    var line = "4353453555k fgafg 4535k"
    line.replace("(\\d*)[k]".toRegex(), "replace with group capture")
```

What I want as a Results:

```
    4353453555 fgafg 4535
```

Comment: What do you want to obtain? What part needs to be removed? Note you need to assign the result back to the variable. `line = line.replace("""(\d*)k""".toRegex(), "replace with group capture")` yields `replace with group capture fgafg replace with group capture`

Comment: It's not direct, but the `replace` docs say *The replacement can consist of any combination of literal text and $-substitutions.*

Comment: So basically i want to just remove the "k" that comes after digits in the string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove `k` that comes after digits, you may use

```
line = line.replace("""(\d+)k""".toRegex(), "$1")
```

Here, `(\d+)k` matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits and then matches `k`, and the `$1` in the replacement pattern inserts Group 1 value back into the resulting string.

Alternatively, you may use a lookbehind based solution:

```
line = line.replace("""(?<=\d)k""".toRegex(), "")
```

See the [online Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/PRS52820).

The `(?<=\d)k` pattern matches a `k` char only if it is immediately preceded with a digit. The `(?<=\d)` pattern is a positive lookbehind that requires the presence of its patten, a digit, immediately to the left of the current location (without putting the text matched into the match buffer, so the replacement is an empty string).

Comment: Thanks I tested both of them and they both worked!
EDIT: I should mention for some reason you have to use double \\ for regex in kotlin.

Comment: @Gary, `\d` in regex is a digit. `\d` in Kotlin is an escape sequence (an invalid one). `\\\d` in Kotlin produces the `\d` regex needs, or you can simply use a raw string like in the answer.

Comment: @Gary See the above comment. Besides, I have provided a demo link to show that you do not have to use double escapes when using raw string literals like `"""...."""`.